# angularjs select ng-click event does not expand the control

Tags: angularjs, select, angularjs-ng-click

I am trying to dynamically load the optionset of select tag on ng-click event. clicking on expand arrow fires ng-click event. Since I fetch the data at that point and bind to the select control, angularjs omits the expand event somehow, select does not expand. User has to click on the arrow one more time to see the results of the dynamically loaded options.

How can I ensure to expand the select correctly in one click while loading the options?

I tried to find a way to dynamically expand the select when the load is complete, but afaik there is no cross browser way of achieving that.

Here is the code, onclick retrieve method is being called to fetch and bind the data to the select. But click does not expand the control...

```
<div style="position: relative;">
    <input type="text" class="inputTextFieldCell"
           style="width: 215px; position: relative; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 2; padding: 0; margin: 0;"
           ng-model="subscriptionResource.Value" />

    <select class="optionsCellInput selectTextFieldCell"
            style="width:240px;position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; padding: 0; margin: 0;"
            ng-click="resources.retrieve(subscriptionResource, $event)"
            ng-model="item" ng-options="resource as resource.Serial for resource in subscriptionResource.resourceList"
            ng-change="selectChange(subscriptionResource, item)" >     
    </select>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$scope.resources = {
    retrieve: function (resource, event) {
        if (resource.resourceList == null) {
            var reqDataRetrieveResources = { "request": null };
            reqDataRetrieveResources = window.createRequest(window.definitions.messages.RetrieveResourceRequest, reqDataRetrieveResources);
            reqDataRetrieveResources.request["ResourceType"] = 1;
            reqDataRetrieveResources.request["SearchCount"] = 5;

            $http.post(window.definitions.url, reqDataRetrieveResources).success(function (result) {
                if ((result.d !== null) && (result.d.Resources !== null)) {
                    resource.resourceList = result.d.Resources;
                    return true;
                }
            });

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide your code?

Comment: thanks, I added the sample code.

Comment: where do you assign the resource.resourceList to the $scope? When the http returns....

Comment: select uses subscriptionResource as model. This model is passed as parameter to the retrieve method on ng-click. When click occurs and  http returns a resourceList, It assigns result to the model parameter's resourceList member, since select uses model's resourceList member in ng-options directive, it populates the options. I know it's little bit complicated but this structure allows me to dynamically populate the option set.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `ng-mousedown` instead of ng-click. If it don't works, try to call `$scope.$apply` after bind your data.

Comment: I added $scope.$apply() right after resource.resourceList = result.d.Resources; line. As far as I know this is where scope apply should be added. Am I missing something.

Comment: In your html code you use subscriptionResource.resourceList, and in your js code you use resource.resourceList. You need to use the same model in js and html files.

Comment: Hi alexandre, resource is the name of the parameter, when calling the method I pass subscriptionResource as parameter, so they are basically the same thing, will it cause any problems?

Comment: Yes, you're right, I'm sorry. Have you initialized your variable? Like $scope.subscriptionResource = {}; $scope.subscriptionResource.resourceList = [];

Comment: subscriptionResource comes from a ng-repeat directive, I initialized resourceList didn't make any difference. It correctly binds the data, I have no problem with that, it's just first click doesn't expand, it only loads the data, second click expands the select control, I want first click to load and expand at the same time.